# MultiImage WindowsPhone7 Control

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox, controls, datatemplate

I am asking about a wp7 control, which presents an image. I don't  know how to do this, and havn't  found this in internet. So i need a control, which has different datatemplate depending on count of images needed to present.
So, if we need present one image - it will fully show it on full control's size.
If there are 2, 3 or 4 images - they must look like in a grid. So their size = size of control / 4.

Examples:
ImageSource has only one Image Item
[image]

ImageSource has four Image Items
[image]

Thanks for advices.

I thought to create usercontrol wich is inherit from ListBox, but i don't know how to realize the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write custom panel, this will be the best way for you. Custom panel will give you speed and flexibility, and implementing it takes 1-2 hours.
See example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/03/creating-a-custom-panel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A wrappanel should work, check the wp7 toolkit on codeplex, it contains such control.
If you add all the images to that control and set there "Stretch" property to "Fill", I assume it should work.

*untested*

Previous failed, as far as I know, you'll have to write something yourself. I haven't encountered such control yet.

Comment: Outputs only one image which stretched as fill